# How do I calculate the air pressure on the maximum bulge of the airfoil?

Tags: aircraft-design, airfoil

[image: Airfoil's cross section and wind direction]
[image: Coanda's effect demonstration]

Picture 2: [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvzXKZNJ7ZU).

Consider I have an airplane and it wing, of course. The cross-section of the airfoil is as the picture 1. The leading edge and the wind direction are depicted there. The leading edge I depicted as simple as possible to make it easy to be understood. It is exactly a half of a circle. For clearer, you may see the second picture or watch the video of the link I provided above.

Then my question is, how do I calculate the air pressure in the leading edge's top bulge as in the first picture?

Comment: What is the final result you would like to get? Lift and drag? Or you need the actual pressure estimate?

Comment: Hey that's exactly what MY head looks like when I blow dry it!

Comment: Quite strange no answer this question.